# Cannot set to submit form by pressing enter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, login-control, enter

I am on vb.net 4.0. I want to press enter to submit my login form. However, I cannot set the btnLogin as default button for submitting my login form. As I use the login page from masterpage template, I set the default button property in contentplaceholder tag but doesn't work. Try to set in the form of masterpage also doesn't work. Should I try other method? or Javascript?

Comment: is it wrapped in a <form runat="server">...</form> tag?

Comment: also, posting your code usually helps.

Comment: code please so that we could help you deal with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a panel around the login form and set the default button on there

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlLogin" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblUsername" Text="Username:" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtUsername" />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblPassword" Text="Password:" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Login" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `defaultbutton` attribute to your `form` tag

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnLogin">

</form>
```